# How do I combine multiple tables into 1 table in powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, exchange-server, powershell-2.0, exchange-server-2007

In powershell I can use the Format-Table command to sort everything in my results; however I have the same script that needs to return data from four servers.  I am going to build an HTML report and send it by email once I can format the table properly, but I don't want 4 tables.  I want all the tables combined into one.  This specifically relates to the Exchange Management Shell and replication health checks.

For examples the command Get-StorageGroupCopyStatus returns information as shown below:

```
Identity    SummaryCopyStatus  CopyQueueLength  ReplayQueueLength
--------    -----------------  ---------------  -----------------
Server\Db   Healthy                0               0
Server\Db   Healthy                0               0
Server\Db   Healthy                0               0
Server\Db   Healthy                0               0
Server\Db   Healthy                0               0
Server\Db   Healthy                0               0
Server\Db   Healthy                0               0
Server\Db   Healthy                0               0
```

I want to combine that output from 4 servers into one large table.  What is the best way to do that in powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you can query your servers from one central location, just execute your commands in a scriptblock and pipe the result to the convertto-html cmdlet.

```
&{Get-StorageGroupCopyStatus SERVERA;Get-StorageGroupCopyStatus SERVERB} | convertto-html
```